Running the plot of Final Fantasy X
FFX is one of my favorite games of all time. The story, world building, themes and plot twists are something I wish more people could experience. No one else in my d&d group has played the game and so I thought it would be a good opportunity to tell the story through a d&d campaign. Others online have had this idea in the past but I haven’t found many tips that would help me run it. For those of you players and DMs who have also played this game, any tips? My first thought is have the player party experience the world through Tidus’s lens, but that would require a lot of dmpcs to guide the party (Yuna, lulu, auron) and I dislike that idea. I could have 1 player take on Yuan’s role but I don’t want to pigeonhole the character into Yuna’s personality for the sake of the plot. My primary concern is what role does the party take?
I ultimately want them to learn about the world, becoming introduced to its mysteries, become invested in defeating sin, feel manipulated by Yevon and finally defeat sin on their own terms. Any tips to make this plot work out without railroading the players too much?

How much DM experience and playing experience do you have? How comfortable are you pressuring the party to stick to the plot as written? How do your prospective players feel about giving up some or most of their agency to follow the predefined plot? Please [edit] in some of this additional context.

Do you want to recreate the whole plot with the same universe and worldbuilding or do you want to create a similar adventure with similar plot twists, power dynamics and archetypes while having your own (heavily inspired) worldbuilding?

Use a very bare bones plot summary and be flexible
I've run campaigns using the plot of video games in the past including Skyrim (twice), The Last of Us, Fallout 4, and most recently Elden Ring. Over these campaigns I've learned a few things and gotten better at realizing what makes a good campaign in these settings. Here are the three main lessons I learned.

Don't use the player characters from the game. I tried using them for Skyrim and The Last of Us and the players were very shoe horned into roles. You seem to have intuited this in your analysis of using Yuna. Have your players build their own characters and just set them in the world at the start of the story.
In my most recent Elden Ring campaign the party started as Tarnished in the Round Table Hold, each of them meeting their finger maidens (if you're familiar with the story of Elden Ring you'll recognize this as a deviation from the main storyline, but it worked better so that no one player is more central to the plot). This gives them player freedom and sets up the story without shoehorning them into the roles of the game.

Pick up on some key pivotal moments to serve as landmark events, you don't need to copy the story exactly.
For my Elden Ring campaign this meant some prime events that fit well with large groups (Frontal Assault on Stormveil Castle, Alliance with Caria Manor to assault the Academy, and Radahn's Festival were the first three major plot points). This won't be as challenging for FFX since multiple characters is expected, but you still want to choose events that your players will be excited to participate in.

(Most importantly) Be willing to stay from the strict lore to add to characters and locations your players become invested in.
Almost invariably your players will be more interested in regions that are less prominent in the game world. In my case it was the Village of the Albinaurics. My players took a more heavy note of their plight so I added more characters and story options in the "early game" for assisting the Village and it became an almost base of operations as the campaign brew on. Be flexible with the world's lore and be willing to do some extra custom work to help your players become invested in the world.


Applying it to FFX
Here are those three ideas roughly applied to FFX:

Perhaps the party is full of travelers who are shipwrecked on Besaid Island. You can still leverage Yuna (who they learn about from other NPCs in the village) but perhaps just as a prominent question giver rather than a main adventurer. This skips a bit of the early game, but jumps right into the main questline so that the players can see the overall objective.

Some major plot points that fit D&Ds storytelling:

Defending Kilika from Sin (it's very hard to do a lost fight in D&D so ensure the focus turns quickly to saving survivors rather than winning the day outright)
Gearing up on Luca and Assaulting Operation Mi'ihen
Dungeon Crawl in Djose Temple (I'd encourage you to make this more of a traditional dungeon crawl as D&D is really good at these)


One example of necessary adaptation is if your party ends up liking Luca a lot. Then you can add some city politics and intrigue (perhaps they investigate a rigged Blitzball game). You can look to Water deep: Dragon Heist for ideas for city adventure elements.
Another might be an interest in the history of the world where you might need to invent past summoners or ancient ruins for them to learn about and explore.


Conclusion
Overall, you primarily are telling a new story that is only partly related to the one of the game. Focus on the elements of the game world your players show interest in and let the D&D game drive the plot rather than the original story.

I appreciate the response and it helps me out a ton. Assuming no characters want to take the summoner role, perhaps I should just use Spira as the sandbox and run the campaign as any other? If the players have natives of Spira as their characters, how much info about the world should I give them before we start? A big part of the game was the player learning about the strange world of Spira through Tidus’s eyes. I think discovering twists such as Yevon’s manipulation and the fact that summoners die during the final summoning really made an impact. Any suggestions for trying to maintain that?

@Jex you can get the same emotional beats by having a prominent NPC be a summoner and the party experience that twist through their interaction with the NPCs. There's countless ways you can have the party "assist" the summoner(s) only to discover towards the end that the summoner has been partially deceived and will end up paying the ultimate price.

@Jex: On top of what David said,it's worth remembering that there are multiple summoners in the original FFX world-you could treat the summoner's questlines a bit like sidequests early on, maybe try and get them assigned to a summoner near the end of the game once they have gotten more familiar with the world, or treat them a bit like how Tomb Of Annihilation provides the party with Guides (Full disclosure-I'm a PC in a campaign of that, and have not actually read the full details about them),and treat the"Big reveals"like side quest incidentals,pacing them out as the party gets to know a few.

An important thing to note about FFX's storytelling is that it relies heavily on Tidus not asking certain questions, and on characters who know plot-relevant information but not revealing it until the appropriate dramatic moment (I'm lookin' at you, Auron). That works fine in a linear JRPG where the writers control what all characters think to say and when, but not in a TRPG where players have every incentive to ask questions like "so what reward will we get at the end of this quest" and "when you say 'Sin is Jecht,' what do you mean, and could you explain now instead of waiting four hours?"

It might be a good idea to lean into summoning as a funereal rite that prevents monsters from overruning the land, instead of focusing on the Pokemon battling aspect. That especially helps if nobody wants to play the summoner, you can really push the idea that a summoner is a critical person with an important mission but doesn't have combat capabilities and needs to be protected by people who do. (A few spells from among the Summon or Call will probably do just fine to give the flavor, if you really want that, though those tend to be a lot weaker than FFX summons.)

I don't know FFX, but if a key element is someone dying, you will need some reason why D&D staples like the resurrection spell don't just solve the issue.

I can only agree with the Use a very bare bones plot summary and be flexible part, I ran Dragon Quest IX as an campaign, and apart from the rough overarching plot (get powers back, collect some McGuffins) and the location of towns, I filled in the construct as needed and depending on how the story unfolds. Don't overprepare.

@JoelHarmon In the game, summoners try to finish a grueling journey that eventually grants them the ability to destroy a kaiju called Sin, at the cost of their life. Sin inevitably reappears after a decade or so and starts wrecking the world again, which starts the whole thing over. There's a secret conspiracy behind why Sin always comes back and what exactly happens to the summoner, but in short, the summoner can't be resurrected because their soul is no longer available.

Don't
Computer role-playing games and table-top role-playing games have a fundamental difference:  Only the latter can truly accommodate player agency.
You say it yourself in the question itself-- you want to run the plot of Final Fantasy.  You recognize it at several points in the extended text of the question.  If you do this, you are by definition constricting the players' agency so that it runs along the rails of the plot you want them to experience.
In other words, you will railroad your players.
If you must do something like this, let them play in this game world, but without the expectation that they will run through a pre-built plot that you want them to experience.

And of all the games you could do this with, FFX is especially rail-roady. It is a very linear, singular narrative, and not conducive to a game that requires agency.

Yeah from the start, I knew I’d have to pitch the campaign as a linear railroad story. But now I’m thinking more along the lines of dropping the players in the world of Spira and letting them determine their own adventure rather than making them a part of a summoner party. It means I’d be giving up the story beats that made the game experience impactful but perhaps that would make the campaign more enjoyable for everyone involved.

To be fair, many official adventures are pretty railroady.

@enkryptor to be fair, many official adventures aren’t very good.

"This is your story."
A lot of DMs set their campaign in an existing videogame world in order to try to capture the feeling they had when playing it. The challenge is that you can't do that just by copying surface details like places and NPCs. You have to think hard about why FFX made you feel that way, and work out how to create a campaign that makes your players feel the same way.
Spira itself is actually an excellent setting for a D&D campaign. There's a clear campaign structure (the pilgrimage), a rationale for the party (the Summoner and her Guardians), a well-defined goal (defeat Sin), solid origin lore for creature types which map easily to existing D&D monsters (fiends = fiends, machina = constructs, sinspawn = aberrations, various humanoid types, unsent perhaps count as celestialssince they're essentially made of the same stuff as fiends, etc).
Here's my advice. Unredacted spoilers for FFX of course follow.

You have to let your players create their own original characters in the world. Yuna isn't the only Summoner in Spira, even during her own pilgrimage. If your players haven't played FFX, they won't be familiar with the characters in order to play them. There's no point in making them DMPCs, because the characters won't have the same meaning the players that they do to you.
On the other hand, if your players have played FFX, or watched a Lets Play of the game, the original game's plot twists won't hit like they did when you played the game. If you have them play the original characters too, then it's just fan character RP, which is fine, but it's not really a D&D campaign. Fundamentally, you can't railroad the players to recreate the story of FFX. You have to let the players make their own decisions and tell their own story.
Accept that some of the plot points will not carry well. A major conceit of FFX is that Tidus, an outsider, is the only person in the world who doesn't know that Yuna is going to die at the end of the pilgrimage, and it only works that way because he never asks.
It's somewhat acceptable to railroad the players from place to place, since FFX takes place across a pilgrimage between pre-determined spots, so the overall path is obvious. However, you have to let the players solve them in your own way. You don't have to stick to the exact route or timeline of FFX. You'll have to invent your own dungeons and puzzles for the temples, in particular, since they won't convert easily to a tabletop game.
Disable raise dead. Aside from the fact that it doesn't canonically appear in FFX, it creates opportunities for the kind of bittersweet moments that define FFX's story. A Guardian sacrificing themself for the Summoner is absolutely appropriate to the lore. Even if the Summoner dies, you can still continue the campaign with another party, but make it clear that the party disbands when the Summoner is killed, being that the Guardians are defined by their bond to the Summoner. (It may be an interesting twist, if the players are really attached to their characters, to continue the campaign and have the Summoner come back, only to be revealed later as an Unsent.)
Mechanically, there is no Summoner class in D&D 5e. Tasha's Cauldron of Everything has some summon spells, although they're spread across classes and not as powerful as the FFX ones. My suggestion is to make the Summoner a cleric (since Yuna is also a healer and a key party member), and give them unique summon spells of each spell level which can only be learned at each of the Temples, and which are always added to spells prepared. Be careful not to make them too powerful. You also can't enforce FFX's rule that the other party members suddenly vacate the field when a summon appears, since D&D doesn't work that way.
Heavy armor isn't a major thing in Spira, probably due to the tropical climate. This is going to reduce AC for some classes.
Consider how D&D's character classes will fit into Spira, and how Spira fits into D&D's rules. You'll need to prepare a document for your players advising them of the races and class options available. I suggest re-skinning existing races to fit Spira's species, perhaps adding a warlock patron equivalent for Sin, re-skinning existing monsters, etc.

The fundamental point I want to make is that D&D is a game of playing your own character and making your own choices. As Auron says to Tidus, "This is your story." You aren't going to evoke the same feelings as FFX just by leading players through the story. You can use the same setting as a backdrop, but from there you have to ask how to recreate the same feeling and tone.

to be fair you can still have heavy armor and just reskin it, also you could use druid instead of cleric and make "summoning" more like an custom elemental wild shape. this covers a lot of the wierd effects of summoning. Or just make it a custom cleric wild shape like effect. you are being possessed by or merging with the summon, thus tansforming into it, which makes compatability important thus why only certain peole can do it.
